# Print preview showing css but document is not

Tags: css, printing, preview

I am using following function to print the div document ,it have some dynamic generated css that is shown in preview but after printing it , it is showing the content but not css.
Please help me .

function PrintPDF(elem)
    {
        Popupnew($(elem).html());
    }

```
function Popupnew(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open("", "mydiv", "height=400,width=600");
    mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Annotated Document</title>");
    mywindow.document.write("<link href='{{asset('bundles/acmeregister/css/style.css') }}' media='print,screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>\n");
    //mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" media="print,screen" src="bundles/acmeregister/importance/rangy-cssclassapplier.js">');
//mywindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" media="print,screen" src="bundles/acmeregister/importance/rangy-highlighter.js">');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(data);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You mean the print preview shows the styles correctly, but the actual printout does not? That does sound like a problem, yes. What browser? Or, are you exporting to a PDF file instead of printing? If so, which PDF export library are you using?

Comment: Also, does it make a difference if you put the styles in a `<style>` element rather than a `<link>`? And, is the resulting HTML error-free?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.Yes, i am using firfox. no i am not exporting pdf file i am just printing the html of div.If i am using styles in <style> element rather than <link> then css was not shown in preview also.

Comment: By doing the following i resolved it
function PrintPDF(){
w=window.open(null, 'Print_Page', 'scrollbars=yes');    
w.document.write("<link href='{{asset('bundles/acmeregister/css/style.css') }}' media='print,screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>\n");     
    w.document.write(jQuery('#texts').html());
    w.document.close();
    w.print();
return (false);
}

Comment: What is the difference ?